# How do I display specific text when an element has true in it?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following element in my xml document

```
<LivesWithIndicator>true</LivesWithIndicator>
```

I would like when LivesWithIndicator has true then display the following

```
<xsl:text>Juvenile lives with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian</xsl:text>
```

**Otherwise when ** 
`<LivesWithIndicator>false/LivesWithIndicator>`

**display**

```
<xsl:text>Juvenile does not live with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian</xsl:text>
```

My xsl code

```
<xsl:value-of select="LivesWithIndicator"/>
```

displays

```
Juvenile lives with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian: true
```

This is not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xsl:choose` here

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="LivesWithIndicator='true'">
       <xsl:text>Juvenile lives with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian</xsl:text>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text>Juvenile does not live with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian</xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Alternatively, you could you a template based approach. Create two templates like so:

```
<xsl:template match="LivesWithIndicator[. = 'true']">
    <xsl:text>Juvenile lives with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LivesWithIndicator">
    <xsl:text>Juvenile does not live with this Parent/Guardian/Custodian</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can do this to output the value

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="LivesWithIndicator" />
```

Comment: I recommend the template based approached.